# git gc can't finish because I'm running out of disk space

Tags: git

I have a big git repository that takes up around 50GB. The hard drive on my macbook doesn't have enough space and so I decided to run git gc to free some space from my git repository.

Unfortunately, I get this error:

"write error: No space left on device
fatal: failed to run repack"

Any suggestions on what to do? My macbook storage is down to 11MB from 10 GB as a result of git gc.

Help sincerely appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like the quickets solution is to find some space to free up. Either find something to delete outright, or attach an external disk/thumb drive/whatever and temporarily move some stuff off.

Comment: External drive. Almost always the way to go - get an external SSD if you want better speed. You can get a (slow) 2 TB external drive for under $100, plenty of room but it will take all day (or all week).